# Receiving an error in Actionscript 3. "Comparison between a value with a static type uint and a possibly unrelated type Array"

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Forgive me for my lack of understanding, I am only a high school student. For a school project, I am tasked with creating a game through Actionscript 3. I have decided to make Brick Breaker, where the objective is to destroy the blocks on stage, etc. One of the features of the game is that blocks with varying types are spawned on screen. The red type can be destroyed in one hit, the blue can be destroyed in two hits and the purple type can be destroyed in three. These three blocks have been added to 'blockArray'.

Basically, when the ball hits one of the blocks, it will lose a health point. When the block has health = 0, then it will remove from stage and Array.

The spawning and collisions of the ball hitting the blocks work just as they should. The problem is pretty much everything else. Let me show you an example:

```
function checkHealth():void
      for (var i:uint=0; i<blockArray.length; i++)
           for (i = 0; i < blockArray; i++)
                health = 1;
           for (i = 1; i < blockArray; i++)
                health = 2;
           for (i = 2; i < blockArray; i++)
                health = 3;
```

I am getting an error from this code saying, "Comparison between a value with a static type uint and a possibly unrelated type Array"

Any help for this is much appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: You are comparing a number with an array. `i < blockarray` This won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you happen to have a suggestion on how to change this? I tried to define what was in the array, and use that instead, but a plethora of new errors arose.

Comment: `i` = number so compare to Number not compare to Array. If you don't understand your own code (a) `blockArray` = an Array called _"blockArray"_ and (b) `blockArray.length` = a Number telling how many items in the array... If `i` is also a Number then which do you think (between _a_ or _b_) is compatible for comparison?

Comment: I would assume it's b) is the most compatible

Comment: What is your intent in that code?  TBH, it doesn't make any sense to me - your code says "For everything in the array, first go through everything in the array and for each one, set health to 1, then skip the first element in the array and set health to 2, then skip the first two elements in the array and set health to 3".  Net result:  `health = 3`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented, I have fixed the problem. I know this code was poorly written and didn't follow conventions, so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code contains some very wrong practices, and doesn't really make sense.

Assuming the second for loop runs 50 times, why would you want to assign the same value to a variable 50 times? "health = 1" can be called only once. Calling it 1 million times wouldn't change the result.

Also, modifying the index value inside the for loop itself is very bug friendly :) I wouldn't do that.
Can you explain better what you want to achieve? By reading this code it is impossible to guess.